# Get part of a string in bash

Tags: bash, grep, substring

I have a few log files and I grep them for specific string:

```
grep UncategorizedLdap *
```

and I get ~33 results:

```
2009-01-01:org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - Operations Error]; remaining name 'ou=ABC'
2009-01-02:org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - Operations Error]; remaining name 'ou='
2009-01-02:org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - Operations Error]; remaining name 'ou=ABD'
2009-01-03:org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - Operations Error]; remaining name 'ou=ABE'
...
```

How can I modify grep call to return only

```
ou=ABC
ou=
ou=ABD
ou=ABE
...
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the output to perl:

```
grep UncategorizedLdap * | perl -lpe '($_) = /(ou=\w*)/'
```

In case you don't have Perl installed, here's a bash-only solution:

```
grep UncategorizedLdap * |
while read line; do
    line=${line#*\'}
    line=${line%\'*}
    echo $line
done
```

Comment: I've installed perl for cygwin but it does not work properly - it prints whole lines.

Comment: @hsz: I guess the problem was in double quotes. I posted another Perl one-liner

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU `grep` (which should be the case in Cygwin):

```
grep -Po "UncategorizedLdap.*'\Kou.*?(?=')" *
```

will select the lines and pick out the string in one command. It uses Perl Compatible Regular Expressions which supports lookarounds. The part before the `\K` is a lookbehind and is used in making the match, but not included in the output. The string inside `(?=)` which is a single quote in this case is the lookahead and it's also not included in the output. The `-o` option prints only the matching part of the line (that's not excluded from output).

Answer (score 1):

if you are using bash, then sometimes you can just use bash

```
for file in *
  while read -r line
  do
     case "$line" in
       *UncategorizedLdap* )
          line=${line#*\'}
          line=${line%\'*}
          echo $line ;;
     esac
  done < $file
done
```